# Min function keeps returning wrong value in loop inR

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to run a loop that returns and stores the minimum value in a sequence. The code however keeps returning the last indexed value of the loop. Here's my function

```
low<- seq(1,100)
five.D_MIN <- c(rep(0, length=length(low)))
for (j in 1:length(five.D_MIN)-4){
  five.D_MIN[j] <- min(low[j:j+4])
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other have stated already, you have to put brackets like `j:(j+4)`. And to make it more stable for length lower than 4 try:

```
low <- seq(1,100)
five.D_MIN <- integer(max(0, length(low) - 4))
for(j in head(seq_along(low), -4)) {
#for(j in seq_len(max(0, length(low) - 4))) { #Alternative
  five.D_MIN[j] <- min(low[j:(j+4)])
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to put additional brackets because your selection is wrong :

```
low<- seq(1,100)
five.D_MIN <- c(rep(0, length=length(low)))
for (j in 1:(length(five.D_MIN)-4)){
  five.D_MIN[j] <- min(low[j:(j+4)])
}
```

Comment: I have tried that too. Putting a bracket returns the following error:

Error in low[j:(j + 4)] : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts

Comment: Check your code or retry copy-paste because my code works fine, because you also made an error where `1:length(five.D_MIN)-4` should be `1:(length(five.D_MIN)-4)`

Answer (score 1):

You missed `()` to surround `j+4`. The difference can be seen from the following example

```
> 1:1 + 4
[1] 5

> 1:(1 + 4)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: I have tried that. It returns the following error:
Error in low[j:(j + 4)] : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts